# How to get status access token without app review ? If i host on my website still i need to give app review for user status data ?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I am developing an app for educational purpose. Any how i want to get status data of user without submitting app for app review process. If i host an app on my website still do i want to submit it for review process to get status data ?

Should i use facebook4j or something like that api to get around this ?

Currently i am using facebook php sdk and hosting app on my website (Option next to canvas page). I am only getting public profile of user.

Is app review still require when app we host on our website (i.e. not using canvas url) ?

Comment: Review is only required if you are going to ask people for permissions that don't have a role on the app. You can ask any person that have a role on the app for any permission without review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All apps, whether hosted on a private server or not, need to get reviewed for additional permissions. Even if your app is for research purposes, the `user_status` permission will need to be reviewed before end-users can use it.

Page apps, Canvas apps or Website apps are all hosted on servers, and not on Facebook. So the same rules apply to all three. The review process applies to all.

You should use the official Facebook PHP SDK to develop your app.

Comment: other ways to get the status data without review ? (oauth)

Comment: No, that's the point. You cannot get additional information from users without approving the additional permissions.